# How to create a network (graph) with the given degree distribution?

Tags: fortran, graph-theory

What I'm going to try to describe now actually comes from a different field of science, but I'll try to explain it using graph theory as analogue. So let's say I have some degree distribution (probability density).
Now, my question is, if I want to create a network which would have the same degree distribution, what would be the fastest/easiest approach? And my problem is the code I'm working on is written in Fortran, so using NetworkX is not an option. The other problem (that comes from my field) is the limits due to maximum distance between nodes (they're already generated), but I think for now I can skip that.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please take the [tour] and learn [ask]. Your question, as it is presented right now, is too unclear and broad to be considered on topic in this site. Please, try to rewrite your question to be more clear and provide some code, preferrably a [mcve].

Comment: This might be better asked over at https://scicomp.stackexchange.com, but do check their Ts and Cs before reposting (and don't cross-post !).  If you do choose to ask it there, I'd suggest being more explicit about the domain you are working in, in my experience computational scientists from discipline X and from discipline Y don't always recognise the similarities between their methods.

Answer (score 0):

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Configuration_model  An algorithm by Newman in "The structure and function of complex networks (2003)". You assign to each node a required degree from your degree sequence, then: choose two nodes with positive degree at random, add an edge between them, reduce their required degrees by one, repeat until all required degrees are 0.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers It is good to include the some salient points in your answer.